# ASP Oracle Connection Error

Tags: asp.net, oracle, connection

I've wrote some connection code in asp for oracle. Its working fine from server A.

When I tried same code from server B it give me error.
Here is the stack trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() +9007
   WebApplication4.Login.submit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +238
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9633194
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

I'm using oracle data access dll. Its version is v2.0.50727.
I downloaded it from nuget.

Comment: Its seems like  you  using Open() method without initializing connection object OR your connection string/connection string name  empty

Comment: show your connection code to check whats the problem can be. the exception u show here its only refer to NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

Run your code using:

1. Debug mode
2. Check connection string if empty
3. Access your database manually to simulate the error

Comment: No, Connection string not empty, I checked it the code in my pc. Connection string is working. Here is one point: this application not working where db located. Basically I connect with DB by real ip. This scenario i also used real ip.

Comment: @MohammadShahnewazSarker if any network issue occurred then null reference error will not come,, check connection object before u call open..

Comment: @Umair Anwar, I told same code run on Server A, but not Server B.

Comment: Kindly check your code where null is coming from, its too obvious the you are encountered a null value.. try to check it.

Comment: soldved.. I used 32bit dll,, 64bit os doing issue. here i'm using oracle.manageddataaccess.dll